# back button in side a dialog box in jquery mobile

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, dialog

I have an android application in which i have a jquery dailog box and it shows some list of folders and when onclick of folder i will get list of files inside the folder.

> The problem is here i need a back button so that i can comeback to
>   list of folders after selecting a file.I want back button inside
>   dialog box to navigate between files and folders.Can anyone please
>   help me how can i get this?